# Normal urls are replaced by redirected 301 rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a virtual host called local.maalumaalu. In htaccess lot of 301 redirection rules are there. My problem is when I have a rule like

> Redirect 301 /special-offers local.maalumaalu/special-offers.html

Then

> local.maalumaalu/special-offers/free-child.html

is redirected to

> local.maalumaalu/special-offers.htmlfree-child.html

which is 'page is not found'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`. `RedirectMatch` has `regex` support:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/special-offers/?$ local.maalumaalu/special-offers.html
```

OR if you want to use mod_rewrite then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^special-offers/?$ /local.maalumaalu/special-offers.html [L,R=301,NC]
```